# Disable WPF RichTextBox text auto wrapping

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox, word-wrap

I am using RichTexbox to display RTF text in my application, depends on windows width RichTextbox text auto wraps to next line!!

I want to disable the text auto warp, instead i want to display scroll bar, Also i don't want to set PageWidth of the FlowDocument to avoid text wrapping (since am displaying RTF text i cant measure the PageWidth based on character/size/Font/Font style of the text because each and every character may contains different font style and size)

```
 <RichTextBox HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">      
   <FlowDocument >
        <Paragraph>
            <Run Text="RichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBoxRichTextBox"/>
        </Paragraph>
   </FlowDocument>
```

Is there any other existing property is there to control auto wrapping or can we handle this without measure text size

I have already discussed about this in [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/614c90de-2e81-4d32-a7f3-0048984627e5/disable-wpf-richtextbox-text-auto-wrapping?forum=wpf) also reffered existing stackflow disussions [WPF RichTextBox word wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589663/wpf-richtextbox-word-wrapping) and [Wpf RichTextBox wrapping problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797814/wpf-richtextbox-wrapping-problems)

Thank you

Santhosh Devi

Comment: `<FlowDocument PageWidth="10000">` - Set the document's PageWidth to a BIG number. This looks like the only option. Why you don't want to set PageWidth ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368047/c-wpf-disable-text-wrap-of-richtextbox/1369184#1369184

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#/WPF: Disable Text-Wrap of RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368047/c-wpf-disable-text-wrap-of-richtextbox)

Comment: I have already tried by assigning PageWidth to a big value but the HorizontalScrollbar is always visible and when i scroll horizontally empty page is scrolling, also there is a chance to text wrap if the bigdata is binded to it.
Thats why am not convinced to set big number to pagewidth...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368047/c-wpf-disable-text-wrap-of-richtextbox

Comment: If you are displaying potentially large chunks of text, a `FlowDocument` is perhaps not the best choice (though it is certainly better than `FixedDocument`).  If you're displaying content with excessively long lines, the document layout/formatting costs may add up significantly as the document grows in size.  Alas, a `FlowDocument` is what you get when you use a `RichTextBox`.  If you _must_ display RTF content, you may not have much of a choice.  But if we knew more about what you are displaying, perhaps we could offer a more appropriate alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third partycontrol **syncfusion** control **SfRichTextBoxAdv** has a solution for this issue